# Define ExecutionStrategy at configuration level in EF core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I do have an application using EF core connected to azure SQL.
We were facing resilience failure , to which adding EnableRetryOnFailure() was the solution which I have configured.

```cs
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<jmasdbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataContext"), sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlActions =>
    {
        sqlActions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
            maxRetryCount: 10,
            maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
            errorNumbersToAdd: null);
    }), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Now, this one would fail when we have BeginTransaction throwing error as below

> "The configured execution strategy
> 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy' does not support user-initiated
> transactions. Use the execution strategy returned by
> 'DbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy()' to execute all the
> operations in the transaction as a retriable unit."

I looked into MS docs and they suggest a way to define Execution strategy manually using ExecuteAsync "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-resilient-entity-framework-core-sql-connections"

This has become pain as we do have more than 25+ places where we have these transactions.

I tried to have custom ExecutionStrategy at DbContext level but that did not help

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConnectionString))
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString, options =>
        {
            options.ExecutionStrategy((dependencies) =>
            {
                return new SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy(dependencies, maxRetryCount: 3, maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), errorNumbersToAdd: new List<int> { 4060 });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Is there any way to have this defined at global level? We do not want different strategy for each operation, whenever there is failure , we want that to be rollback completely and start from beginning.

Comment: Please edit your question and post code instead of images. Images cannot be copied or indexed for search.

Comment: Thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv, I have added the code instead of images.